# NSMutableArray of Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

First off I am very new to Objective C and iPhone programming. Now that that is out of the way. I have read through most of the Apple documentation on this and some third party manuals.

I guess I just want to know if I'm going about this the correct way ...

```
- (NSMutableArray *)makeModel {

    NSString *api = @"http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1";

    NSArray *namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"News", @"Sports", @"Entertainment", @"Business", @"Features", nil];

    NSArray *urlsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/news/25/stories.json", api],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/sports/25/stories.json", api],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/entertainment/25/stories.json", api],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/business/25/stories.json", api],
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/features/25/stories.json", api], nil];

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < [namesArray count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *objectDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSString *name = (NSString *)[namesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *url = (NSString *)[urlsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [objectDict setObject:name forKey:@"NAME"];
        [objectDict setObject:url forKey:@"URL"];
        [objectDict setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"HASSTORIES"];
        [result addObject:objectDict];
    }

    return result;
}
```

The output of the result is ...

```
(
    {
    HASSTORIES = NO;
    NAME = News;
    URL = "http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1/news/news/25/stories.json";
},
    {
    HASSTORIES = NO;
    NAME = Sports;
    URL = "http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1/news/sports/25/stories.json";
},
    {
    HASSTORIES = NO;
    NAME = Entertainment;
    URL = "http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1/news/entertainment/25/stories.json";
},
    {
    HASSTORIES = NO;
    NAME = Business;
    URL = "http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1/news/business/25/stories.json";
},
    {
    HASSTORIES = NO;
    NAME = Features;
    URL = "http://www.mycoolnewssite.com/api/v1/news/features/25/stories.json";
}
)
```

Any insight would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: Maybe... What are you trying to accomplish? (e.g. what part are you checking for correctness?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks fine. There can be some minor improvements if you care.

**1.**

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/news/news/25/stories.json", api]
```

can be replaced by

```
[api stringByAppendingString:@"/news/news/25/stories.json"]
```

if there's no chance the `api` appears in the middle or accepts other arguments.

**2.**

```
    NSString *name = (NSString *)[namesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *url = (NSString *)[urlsArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

The explicit cast is unnecessary. An `id` can be implicitly casted to and from other ObjC objects.

**3.**

You could use a convenient method `-dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` to construct the dictionary in one-shot, so you don't need a temperary dictionary:

```
[result addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   name, @"NAME",
   url, @"URL",
   @"NO", @"HASSTORIES", nil]];
```

**4. (optional)**

*This transform is not useful if the function is not a hot spot.*

Since the arrays are only used locally, it's more efficient to use a C array.

```
static const int arraySize = 5;
NSString* namesCArray[] = {@"News", @"Sports", @"Entertainment", @"Business", @"Features"};
NSString* urlsCArray[arraySize];
urlsArray[0] = [api stringByAppendingString:@"/news/news/25/stories.json"];
...
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++ i) {
  ...
  NSString* name = namesCArray[i];
  NSString* url = urlsCArray[i];
  ...
}
```

this removes the repeated `-count` and `-objectAtIndex:` calls which is very slow compared with direct element access.

**5. (optional)**

*This transform is not useful if the array is short.*

You could use fast-enumeration to loop over an ObjC container:

```
int i = 0;
for (NSString* name in namesArray) {
  NSString* url = [urlsArray objectAtIndex:i];
  ...
  ++ i;
}
```

**6.**

Usually we use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` to represent a boxed true/false value, instead of a string `@"NO"`. NSNumber is also used a lot whenever a primitive number (`int`, `float`, etc.) cannot be used (e.g. to be stored in an NSArray). I don't know if your API explicitly requires a string NO, so it may not unsuitable for you.

Comment: WOW! This is great stuff Kenny. I now have a lot more studying to do on these topics. Thanks for sending me in different directions ;-)

Comment: By the way Kenny. I donated $5 to your Google Code project at http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/

Thanks again ;-)

Comment: Terry,  I would seriously look at http://ericasadun.com/ and read the iPhone Cookbook.  It got me up and going inside of 2 weeks.  I was a perl programmer and Erica's book familiarized me enough with the essentials and some neat tricks.  ps:  Good question, tho.